# RAM Upgrade Confusion

Tags: memory, ddr3

I have a Zoostorm PC with a ASUS B85M-GAMER Motherboard. I decided today I wanted to upgrade the RAM, as I will be installing an SSD, but was intrigued to find the 12 GB of RAM was two sticks;

- RAM Stick #1 – 8 GB DDR3 – 1600 UDIMM 1.5V CL13
- RAM Stick #2 – 4 GB DDR3 – 1600 (PC3 12800) UDIM

These are the original RAM sticks, but I'm really confused, as firstly, I thought RAM had to be the same size ideally, and secondly, one stick is UDIM, one is UDIMM, and they both have different product numbers etc. (although looking the same)

I would like to upgrade a further 16 GB of RAM, but am unsure whether two 8 GB sticks is best, or whether I should use 8 GB and 4 GB, like the PC already contains?

Comment: There is no such thing as UDIM.  If you only have two DDR3 slots there is only one way to get to 16GB and that's 8GB+8GB

Comment: Hello, sorry not sure what you mean - here is a screenshot of the two RAM sticks I have (sorry for poor quality) https://i.imgsafe.org/71cdeaed2b.jpeg

Comment: It's a misprint on the label like I said there is no such thing as a UDIM when it comes to computers. The 4GB stick isn't compatible with your pc

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the label was limited in a way where the last letter is cut off. Both of the original RAMs are DDR3 1600MHz UDIMM, so it should work fine, and I assume it did.

Before upgrading, you need to make sure your processor can handle that much RAM, go to [Intel Ark](https://ark.intel.com/), find your processor, then look for "Max Memory Size" under "Memory Specifications".

To get 16GB, the obvious thing to do is to upgrade the 4GB RAM stick to 8GB. Note that this upgrade will not affect your system too much. If you are running out of RAM and your processor can handle more than 16GB, you may want to upgrade the 4GB RAM stick to 16GB instead. Either way, when buying new RAM stick, make sure it is DDR3 1600MHz UDIMM to ensure compatibility.

Comment: Yes, it has been working fine for around a year, no problems at all, thanks. I checked the processor, and the max memory is 32GB - I have 4 RAM slots, so if I were to keep the 8GB and 4GB stick right now, and add two additional 8GB sticks, would that work?

Comment: @Alex Yes, that would work. However, it might slow down your system since you are mixing 3 different RAM sticks together. If you need more than 16GB chances are you are doing some serious work on your PC, if your budget allows, you should consider buying 4 new exact same 8GB RAM sticks. When RAM sticks have different timing, the best scenario is that all RAMs will wait for the one RAM that has the longest timing, depending on the RAMs and memory controller, they might wait for even longer.

Comment: @Alex Most processor only support dual channel, therefore having 4 sticks instead of 2 sticks will not double the performance. The memory controller can only talk to one of the two RAMs that are on the same channel at one time. If you are looking to speed up your PC, then you should buy 2 identical 8GB RAMs and replace the old ones.

Comment: Ah how interesting, I didn't know that - so it's virtually pointless to even upgrade the RAM, as I'd only be getting an extra 4GB? So when you said earlier to buy 4 X 8GB sticks, that's also not worth doing?

Comment: @Alex It depend on your goal. If you use virtual machine or other RAM consuming software that depend on RAM size rather than speed, then I recommend buying four identical 8GB RAMs. If you play games, getting 4 RAM sticks can slow down your system due to having 2 RAM sticks per channel. If you are looking for gaming performance, either leave it as-is or get 2 identical RAM sticks and replace the old ones, there is no point in replacing that 4GB RAM alone, it won't speed up your system and you only risk to make things worse.

Comment: @Alex Also, when installing RAM, make sure to put them on different channel, otherwise it will cut the speed by more than half. Channels are usually color coded (which is the case for your motherboard). Note that it is possible for your processor to support quad channel, if you can put down your full spec with what you do with your PC, I can give you a recommendation on how to speed it up.

Comment: Right, great info - so I'm not a gamer, but do quite a bit of work with media, i.e. video production, and also deal with a large number of files, so I think an SSD may be a suitable route. I just fancied a RAM upgrade as, despite a fairly decent computer spec, it seems to have slowed a lot as of the last few months, particularly in light of a few recent Windows 10 updates.

Comment: @Alex For video production, 16GB of RAM will be plenty, 12GB shouldn't be the problem here. Video rendering heavily uses HDD/SSD, CPU, and graphics card. Getting a SSD and put files you are working with into it will significantly reduce rendering time if your CPU and graphics card are decent. Can you tell me what CPU and graphics card you are using so I can check if they can cause bottleneck?

Comment: Sure, I have a intel (R) Core (TM) i5-4690 CPU @ 3.50GHz processor - is that what you meant? My graphics card is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960 - hope that helps

Comment: @Alex Yep, those are very good, the HDD is the problem then. Get an SSD to put files you are working on into it will significantly speed up rendering time. If your whole system feels slow though, there might be a software issue somewhere.